# Jenkin UI, Filter by name (with regular expression) Regular expression does not detect the branch named with forward slash

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, devops

Problem:

Filter by name (with regular expression)
Regular expression

Given Expression: Attached the image.

It is recognising 'TestJenkins' and 'testJenkins' but it is not matching 'dev/ui-testing'

any idea what is wrong in regex.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You could try (^dev.ui-testing)

Comment: @DrHopfen: I have tried this and it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replacing the / with its URI encoded value, %2F, worked for me, e.g.

```
dev%2Fui-testing
```